# How to access (mysql) host port from docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a host that runs a native `mysql` installation (not a container).

From a `docker` container I now want to connect from a `java` `spring-boot` application to that port (`3306` by default).

But it does not work:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  customer-app:
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
```

Result from `docker-compose up`:

```
Cannot start service customer-app: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint:
Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use
```

This is probably not a question directly to a java application, but more general:

How can I access a port on the *host* system from inside a *docker container*?

Comment: localhost inside a container acts the same way as the loopback on a host machine. I.e. your container tries to connect to itself.

Comment: maybe try `network_mode: host` for the container

Comment: Here you are telling docker to create your customer-app on port 3306 which is already used for your local mysql installation. @tbjorch gave you the good process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following to `docker-compose.yml`:

```
extra_hosts:
  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
environment:
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/db
```